# sqlserver 2000: how to make aynchoronous call to procedures in database?

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, asynchronous

1. back end java 1.4 with EJB 3.2
2. data base sql server 2000

How to make asynchoronous call to a procedure from java code using jdbc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should not be any different then any other asynchronous call. Nothing special about an asynchronous call against a sql server using jdbc.